# Filtering array by ISODate by Month in nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

given this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fixflex",
    "description": "Duis mattis egestas metus. Aenean fermentum. Donec ut mauris eget massa tempor convallis. Nulla neque libero, convallis eget, eleifend luctus, ultricies eu, nibh. Quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum.",
    "category": "c7",
    "startDate": { "$date": "2021-05-12T19:17:52.000Z" }
  },
  {
    "name": "Fixflex",
    "description": "In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo.",
    "category": "c3",
    "startDate": { "$date": "2020-11-07T09:47:00.000Z" }
  },
  {
    "name": "Cookley",
    "description": "Nunc purus. Phasellus in felis. Donec semper sapien a libero. Nam dui. Proin leo odio, porttitor id, consequat in, consequat ut, nulla. Sed accumsan felis.",
    "category": "c6",
    "startDate": { "$date": "2020-03-07T10:09:39.000Z" }
  },
  {
    "name": "Bigtax",
    "description": "Morbi non quam nec dui luctus rutrum. Nulla tellus. In sagittis dui vel nisl. Duis ac nibh. Fusce lacus purus, aliquet at, feugiat non, pretium quis, lectus. Suspendisse potenti.",
    "category": "c7",
    "startDate": { "$date": "2020-09-14T23:51:53.000Z" }
  },
  {
    "name": "Alphazap",
    "description": "Vestibulum quam sapien, varius ut, blandit non, interdum in, ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis faucibus accumsan odio. Curabitur convallis. Duis consequat dui nec nisi volutpat eleifend. Donec ut dolor. Morbi vel lectus in quam fringilla rhoncus.",
    "category": "c7",
    "startDate": { "$date": "2020-04-16T01:30:30.000Z" }
  }
]
```

I would like to filter the by month.
So far I have this in my contoller:

```
exports.getAllWorkouts = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { startDate, category } = req.query;

  try {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;

    let workouts = await Workout.find();
    let filtered = await Workout.find({ category });
    const pageSize = 20;
    let pager = paginate(workouts.length, page, pageSize);
    // get page of workouts from items array
    let pageOfItems = workouts.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);

    // FILTER BY CATEGORY LOGIC
    if (category) {
      pageOfItems = filtered.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
      pager = paginate(filtered.length, page, pageSize);
      return res.json({ pager, pageOfItems });
    }
    // FILTER BY DATE LOGIC
    if (startDate !== undefined) {
      pageOfItems = await Workout.find({ startDate });
      return res.json({ pager, pageOfItems });
    } else {
      return res.json({ pager, pageOfItems });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I use Redux with axios on the client side to make API calls. It looks like this:

```
export const getAllWorkouts = (page, limit, category, startDate) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/api/v1/workout?&page=${page}&limit=${limit}&category=${category}&startDate=${moment(
        startDate
      )}`
    );
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ALL_WORKOUTS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I use React-DateTime. When I choose a new date:

1. It selects the day after
2. When I console.log the request it shows always the today's date.

I can make successful calls in Postman.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the frontend you are sending date/time as local time zone and in the server you are using UTC format, hence the issue.

So convert the date/time to utc before sending it to the server.

```js
export const getAllWorkouts = (page, limit, category, startDate) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    startDate = new Date(startDate).toISOString(); //<----like this
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/api/v1/workout?&page=${page}&limit=${limit}&category=${category}&startDate=${moment(
        startDate
      )}`
    );
...
```

See a [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datetime-issue-fix-w6iwm?file=/src/index.js)

**Side note** - there is a [prop called utc](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime#api) in react-datetime, see if you can make use of it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly when I add that line, first the items are not loading at all. If I select a date it is throwing me an error of cannot map of undefined.
If I remove the line you provided...all items are loading, but not filtering on selecting a new date.

Comment: I am happy to share the repo with you. If you want.

Comment: what is your github username? I send you an invite